# Is it safe to switch theme in drupal on my site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a website with Drupal CMS behind it. I use a custom theme and I would like to change it but I am not sure if it is entirely safe, i.e. is it possible to lose some data, design, etc if I switch it back to my theme? What about blocks and their position if the theme uses different blocks layout. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be safe, but you should have a current backup of the database and files anyways. You can (and probably should) set the administration theme to one of the standard themes, so you can't lock yourself out of the admin section if you break your custom theme.

If the regions are named different (or missing in one theme) you may have to move your blocks. The blocks are set seperately for every theme, so just enable the second theme (without setting it a default) and set the blocks for this theme. After that you can set the theme as default.

I use a copy of the website to try out bigger changes to the site, so that I never break the live site. It makes it much easier and safer to just try out stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are configured per theme. You won't lose any data.

Answer (score 0):

You will not lose any data but your block positioning may change depending on how the theme is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Like some others have said, you won't lose data, but I've typically had to position the blocks when changing themes.

If you enable the new theme (don't set it to default yet) you can setup the blocks before you go live with it. And if you allow certain users to change themes, you can view and tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

You won't lose any data, though you might have to re-position the blocks as per the new theme layout.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else said, you will not lose data. I would like to add if you switch from a theme that has, say two columns, to a one column theme, the blocks from the second column will have to go somewhere (they would need to be manually set).